# After installing Ubuntu 20.04, Lenovo P340 tiny restarting and opening the BIOS

Tags: boot, uefi, lenovo, boot-repair

Ubuntu 20.04 installation went smooth from an external USB drive. The live Ubuntu is booted in UEFI mode and the installation went fine. The Lenovo P340 tiny comes with a PCIe NVME SSD and it is detected automatically. I created an EFI partition to get the UEFI boot working.

After the installation, the system is not booting, few seconds after it start loading, it automatically restart to the BIOS screen. The USB drive is still booting and on the Live Ubuntu, I tired to mount the NVME volume, the partitions are fine and data is there.

Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the system booting properly. It was an issue with grub installation. Grub some how could not detect the NVME partitions and not able to find the OS/Kernel. When I install Ubuntu 20.04, everything worked as expected, except grub. It could not find the kernel from the NVME partition nvme0n1p1 and installed the boot loader menu only with the Load BIOS (uefi-firmware). The system was automatically rebooting to BIOS due to this.

To fix this, I boot to Live Ubuntu 20.04 from USB. (F12 on boot will list all the boot devices). Install the awesome [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool and execute it. It properly detected the kernel this time and installed grub with proper boot menu options.

The issue is resolved and I am now able to boot to p340 Tiny using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What's your experience up to now? Any other issues with Ubuntu on this system? Does everything work as expected?